# How to show the following problem regarding determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, complex-numbers, determinant

Let $n \in \mathbb{N},n \ge 2,$ and $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R}).$ Prove that there exists a complex number $z,$ such that $|z|=1$ and $$\Re \left( {\det(A+zB)} \right) \ge \det(A)+\det(B),$$where $\Re(w)$ is the real part of the complex number $w$.

We know that $f(z)=\det(A+zB)$  is a polynomial in $z$. Can we use this idea?

Comment: Note that every $z \in \mathbb{C}$ can be represented as $z = e^{i \varphi}$ for some $\varphi \in [0, 2 \pi)$.

Comment: Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity (say, $e^{2\pi i/n}$). Let $U$ be the sum $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \det\left(A+\zeta^i B\right)$. It is clearly enough to prove that $\mathfrak{R}\left(U\right) \geq n \left( \det A + \det B \right)$, because then it follows that at least one $i \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$ satisfies $\mathfrak{R}\left(\det\left(A+\zeta^i B\right)\right) \geq \det A + \det B$. So let me prove this. Better yet, I claim that $U = n \left( \det A + \det B \right)$. Why? ...

Comment: ... Consider the polynomial $\det\left(A+xB\right) \in \mathbb{R}\left[X\right]$. This is a polynomial of degree $\leq n$ in $x$; its $x^0$-coefficient is $\det A$, while its $x^n$-coefficient is $\det B$. (This follows, e.g., from the equality (4) in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2189752/ .) Now, what happens if you evaluate a polynomial of degree $\leq n$ at all the $n$-th roots of unity $\zeta^0, \zeta^1, \ldots, \zeta^{n-1}$ and sum the results? This is the famous "roots of unity filter"; the result is $n$ times the sum of the $x^0$-coefficient with the $x^n$-coefficient (since ...

Comment: ... all other coefficients of the polynomial cancel out via discrete-Fourier "destructive interference"). So $U = n\left(\det A + \det B\right)$, as desired.

Comment: @darijgrinberg looks like an answer to me...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I sketched in the comments, in more detail.

I will prove a more general statement:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $A,B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times
> n}$ be two complex matrices. Then, there exists a complex number $z$ on the
>   unit circle (actually, an $n$-th root of unity) such that
>   \begin{equation}
> \operatorname*{Re}\left(  \det\left(  A+zB\right)  \right)  \geq
> \operatorname*{Re}\left(  \det A+\det B\right)  .
> \label{darij1.eq.t1.eq}
> \tag{1}
> \end{equation}

Here, I am using the notation $\operatorname*{Re}w$ for the real part of a
complex number. (You are using $\mathfrak{R}\left(  w\right)  $ for this.)

Theorem 1 generalizes your question, because if $A,B$ are real matrices, then
$\operatorname*{Re}\left(  \det A+\det B\right)  =\det A+\det B$.

In order to prove Theorem 1, we need some notations regarding polynomials. We
set $\mathbb{N}=\left\{  0,1,2,\ldots\right\}  $.

> **Definition.** Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a commutative ring, and let $f\in
> \mathbb{K}\left[  t\right]  $ be a polynomial. For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we
>   let $\left[  t^{n}\right]  f$ denote the coefficient of $t^{n}$ in the
>   polynomial $f$.

Thus, any polynomial $f\in\mathbb{K}\left[  t\right]  $ satisfies
$f=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\left(  \left[  t^{k}\right]  f\right)  \cdot t^{k}$.

We recall a basic property of determinants:

> **Proposition 2.** Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a commutative ring. Let $n\in
> \mathbb{N}$. Let $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$
>   be two $n\times n$-matrices. Consider the matrix $tA+B\in\left(
> \mathbb{K}\left[  t\right]  \right)  ^{n\times n}$.
>
> **(a)** Then, $\det\left(  tA+B\right)  \in\mathbb{K}\left[  t\right]  $ is a
>   polynomial of degree $\leq n$ in $t$.
>
> **(b)** We have $\left[  t^{0}\right]  \left(  \det\left(  tA+B\right)
> \right)  =\det B$.
>
> **(c)** We have $\left[  t^{n}\right]  \left(  \det\left(  tA+B\right)
> \right)  =\det A$.

Proposition 2 appears as Proposition 2.2 in [my note *The trace
Cayley-Hamilton theorem*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/trach.pdf) (which has gradually become a grab-bag for proofs
about characteristic polynomials). It also follows from "the final result" in
Giuseppe Negro's answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2189752/ . You
probably already know why it is true by the time you have finished reading the
preceding two sentences.

On the other hand, we recall a basic property of roots of unity:

> **Proposition 3.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $\zeta$ be a primitive
>   $n$-th root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then:
>
> **(a)** If $n\nmid k$, then $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\zeta^{jk}=0$.
>
> **(b)** If $n\mid k$, then $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\zeta^{jk}=n$.

Proposition 3 is the engine behind the Discrete Fourier Transform. For the
sake of completeness, let me prove it:

*Proof of Proposition 3.* We have $\zeta^{n}=1$ (since $\zeta$ is an $n$-th
root of unity), hence $\zeta^{nk}=\left(  \underbrace{\zeta^{n}}_{=1}\right)
^{k}=1^{k}=1$.

**(a)** Assume that $n\nmid k$. Then, $\zeta^{k}\neq1$ (since $\zeta$ is a
**primitive** $n$-th root of unity). Hence, $\zeta^{k}-1\neq0$. Now, set
$\alpha=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\zeta^{jk}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\zeta^{k}\underbrace{\alpha}_{=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\zeta^{jk}}  &
=\zeta^{k}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\zeta^{jk}=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}
\underbrace{\zeta^{k}\zeta^{jk}}_{=\zeta^{k+jk}=\zeta^{\left(  j+1\right)  k}
}=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\zeta^{\left(  j+1\right)  k}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}
\zeta^{jk}\\
& \qquad\left(  \text{here, we have substituted }j\text{ for }j+1\text{ in the
sum}\right)  \\
& =\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\zeta^{jk}+\underbrace{\zeta^{nk}}_{=1}=\sum_{j=1}
^{n-1}\zeta^{jk}+1.
\end{align*}
Comparing this with
\begin{equation}
\alpha=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\zeta^{jk}=\underbrace{\zeta^{0k}}_{=\zeta
^{0}=1}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\zeta^{jk}=1+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\zeta^{jk}=\sum
_{j=1}^{n-1}\zeta^{jk}+1,
\end{equation}
we obtain $\zeta^{k}\alpha=\alpha$. Hence, $\zeta^{k}\alpha-\alpha=0$, so that
$\left(  \zeta^{k}-1\right)  \alpha=\zeta^{k}\alpha-\alpha=0$. We can divide
this equality by $\zeta^{k}-1$ (since $\zeta^{k}-1\neq0$), and thus obtain
$\alpha=0$. Hence, $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\zeta^{jk}=\alpha=0$. This proves
Proposition 3 **(a)**.

**(b)** Assume that $n\mid k$. Then, $\zeta^{k}=1$ (since $\zeta$ is an $n$-th
root of unity). Now,
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\underbrace{\zeta^{jk}}_{=\zeta^{kj}=\left(  \zeta
^{k}\right)  ^{j}}=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(  \underbrace{\zeta^{k}}
_{=1}\right)  ^{j}=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\underbrace{1^{j}}_{=1}
=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}1=n.
\end{equation}
This proves Proposition 3 **(b)**. $\blacksquare$

Next, we put Proposition 3 to use in establishing the so-called
*roots-of-unity filter* (in one of its simplest forms):

> **Proposition 4.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $\zeta$ be a primitive
>   $n$-th root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $f\in\mathbb{C}\left[  t\right]  $
>   be a polynomial. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}f\left(  \zeta^{j}\right)  =n\sum_{\substack{k\in
> \mathbb{N};\\n\mid k}}\left[  t^{k}\right]  f.
> \end{equation}

*Proof of Proposition 4.* Recall that $f=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\left(  \left[
t^{k}\right]  f\right)  \cdot t^{k}$ (since $\left[  t^{0}\right]  f,\left[
t^{1}\right]  f,\left[  t^{2}\right]  f,\ldots$ are the coefficients of the
polynomial $f$). Hence, for each $j\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have
\begin{equation}
f\left(  \zeta^{j}\right)  =\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\left(  \left[  t^{k}\right]
f\right)  \cdot\underbrace{\left(  \zeta^{j}\right)  ^{k}}_{=\zeta^{jk}}
=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\left(  \left[  t^{k}\right]  f\right)  \cdot\zeta^{jk}.
\end{equation}
Summing this equality over all $j\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  $, we
find
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}f\left(  \zeta^{j}\right)    & =\underbrace{\sum
\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}}_{=\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}
\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}}\left(  \left[  t^{k}\right]  f\right)  \cdot
\zeta^{jk}=\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(  \left[
t^{k}\right]  f\right)  \cdot\zeta^{jk}\\
& =\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\left(  \left[  t^{k}\right]  f\right)
\cdot\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\zeta^{jk}\\
& =\sum\limits_{\substack{k\in\mathbb{N};\\n\nmid k}}\left(  \left[
t^{k}\right]  f\right)  \cdot\underbrace{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\zeta^{jk}
}_{\substack{=0\\\text{(by Proposition 3 (a))}}}+\sum\limits_{\substack{k\in
\mathbb{N};\\n\mid k}}\left(  \left[  t^{k}\right]  f\right)  \cdot
\underbrace{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\zeta^{jk}}_{\substack{=n\\\text{(by
Proposition 3 (b))}}}\\
& \qquad\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{c}
\text{since each }k\in\mathbb{N}\text{ satisfies either }n\nmid k\\
\text{or }n\mid k\text{, but not both at the same time}
\end{array}
\right)  \\
& =\underbrace{\sum\limits_{\substack{k\in\mathbb{N};\\n\nmid k}}\left(
\left[  t^{k}\right]  f\right)  \cdot0}_{=0}+\sum\limits_{\substack{k\in
\mathbb{N};\\n\mid k}}\left(  \left[  t^{k}\right]  f\right)  \cdot
n=\sum\limits_{\substack{k\in\mathbb{N};\\n\mid k}}\left(  \left[
t^{k}\right]  f\right)  \cdot n\\
& =n\sum_{\substack{k\in\mathbb{N};\\n\mid k}}\left[  t^{k}\right]  f.
\end{align*}
This proves Proposition 4. $\blacksquare$

Combining Proposition 2 with Proposition 4, we obtain the following:

> **Corollary 5.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $\zeta$ be a primitive
>   $n$-th root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and
>   $B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be two $n\times n$-matrices. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\det\left(  \zeta^{j}A+B\right)  =n\left(  \det A+\det
> B\right)  .
> \end{equation}

*Proof of Corollary 5.* Define a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{C}\left[  t\right]  $
by $f=\det\left(  tA+B\right)  $. Then, Proposition 2 **(a)** (applied to
$\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$) shows that $\det\left(  tA+B\right)  \in
\mathbb{C}\left[  t\right]  $ is a polynomial of degree $\leq n$ in $t$. In
other words, $f\in\mathbb{C}\left[  t\right]  $ is a polynomial of degree
$\leq n$ in $t$ (since $f=\det\left(  tA+B\right)  $). Thus, $\left[
t^{u}\right]  f=0$ for all integers $u>n$. Thus, the coefficients $\left[
t^{2n}\right]  f,\left[  t^{3n}\right]  f,\left[  t^{4n}\right]  f,\ldots$ are
all $0$ (since the integers $2n,3n,4n,\ldots$ are all $>n$).

Proposition 2 **(b)** (applied to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$) yields $\left[
t^{0}\right]  \left(  \det\left(  tA+B\right)  \right)  =\det B$. In view of
$f=\det\left(  tA+B\right)  $, this rewrites as $\left[  t^{0}\right]  f=\det
B$.

Proposition 2 **(c)** (applied to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$) yields $\left[
t^{n}\right]  \left(  \det\left(  tA+B\right)  \right)  =\det A$. In view of
$f=\det\left(  tA+B\right)  $, this rewrites as $\left[  t^{n}\right]  f=\det
A$.

But we have $f=\det\left(  tA+B\right)  $. Hence, for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$, we
have
\begin{equation}
f\left(  z\right)  =\det\left(  zA+B\right)
\label{darij1.pf.cor5.1}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
(because if we plug $z$ for $t$ into the matrix $tA+B$ and then we take the
determinant, then we obtain the same result as if we first take the
determinant and then plug $z$ for $t$ in it).

Proposition 4 yields
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}f\left(  \zeta^{j}\right)    & =n\underbrace{\sum
_{\substack{k\in\mathbb{N};\\n\mid k}}\left[  t^{k}\right]  f}
_{\substack{=\left[  t^{0}\right]  f+\left[  t^{n}\right]  f+\left[
t^{2n}\right]  f+\left[  t^{3n}\right]  f+\cdots\\\text{(since the }
k\in\mathbb{N}\text{ satisfying }n\mid k\\\text{are }0,n,2n,3n,\ldots\text{)}
}}\\
& =n\underbrace{\left(  \left[  t^{0}\right]  f+\left[  t^{n}\right]
f+\left[  t^{2n}\right]  f+\left[  t^{3n}\right]  f+\cdots\right)
}_{\substack{=\left[  t^{0}\right]  f+\left[  t^{n}\right]  f\\\text{(since
the coefficients }\left[  t^{2n}\right]  f,\left[  t^{3n}\right]  f,\left[
t^{4n}\right]  f,\ldots\text{ are all }0\text{)}}}\\
& =n\left(  \underbrace{\left[  t^{0}\right]  f}_{=\det B}+\underbrace{\left[
t^{n}\right]  f}_{=\det A}\right)  =n\left(  \det B+\det A\right)  \\
& =n\left(  \det A+\det B\right)  .
\end{align*}
Comparing this with
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\underbrace{f\left(  \zeta^{j}\right)  }
_{\substack{=\det\left(  \zeta^{j}A+B\right)  \\\text{(by
\eqref{darij1.pf.cor5.1}, applied to }z=\zeta^{j}\text{)}}}=\sum_{j=0}
^{n-1}\det\left(  \zeta^{j}A+B\right)  ,
\end{equation}
we obtain
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\det\left(  \zeta^{j}A+B\right)  =n\left(  \det A+\det
B\right)  .
\end{equation}
This proves Corollary 5. $\blacksquare$

Now we can prove Theorem 1:

*Proof of Theorem 1.* Choose any primitive $n$-th root of unity in
$\mathbb{C}$ (for example, $e^{2\pi i/n}$), and denote it by $\zeta$. We claim
that there exists some $j\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  $ such that
\begin{equation}
\operatorname*{Re}\left(  \det\left(  A+\zeta^{j}B\right)  \right)
\geq\operatorname*{Re}\left(  \det A+\det B\right)  .
\label{darij1.pf.t1.1}
\tag{3}
\end{equation}

[*Proof:* Assume the contrary. Thus, no $j\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}
$ satisfies
\eqref{darij1.pf.t1.1}. In other words, each $j\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots
,n-1\right\}  $ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\operatorname*{Re}\left(  \det\left(  A+\zeta^{j}B\right)  \right)
<\operatorname*{Re}\left(  \det A+\det B\right)  .
\end{equation}
Summing up these inequalities over all $j\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}
$, we obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\operatorname*{Re}\left(  \det\left(  A+\zeta^{j}B\right)
\right)    & <\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\operatorname*{Re}\left(  \det A+\det B\right)
=n\operatorname*{Re}\left(  \det A+\det B\right)  \nonumber\\
& =n\operatorname*{Re}\left(  \det B+\det A\right)
.
\label{darij1.pf.t1.1.pf.1}
\tag{4}
\end{align}
But Corollary 5 (applied to $B$ and $A$ instead of $A$ and $B$) yields
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\det\left(  \zeta^{j}B+A\right)  =n\left(  \det B+\det
A\right)  .
\end{equation}
Taking real parts on both sides of this equality, we find
\begin{align}
\operatorname*{Re}\left(  \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\det\left(  \zeta^{j}B+A\right)
\right)  =\operatorname*{Re}\left(  n\left(  \det B+\det A\right)  \right)
=n\operatorname*{Re}\left(  \det B+\det A\right)  ,
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align*}
n\operatorname*{Re}\left(  \det B+\det A\right)    & =\operatorname*{Re}
\left(  \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\det\left(  \zeta^{j}B+A\right)  \right)  \\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\operatorname*{Re}\left(  \det\underbrace{\left(  \zeta
^{j}B+A\right)  }_{=A+\zeta^{j}B}\right)  =\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\operatorname*{Re}
\left(  \det\left(  A+\zeta^{j}B\right)  \right)  \\
& <n\operatorname*{Re}\left(  \det B+\det A\right)
\end{align*}
(by
\eqref{darij1.pf.t1.1.pf.1}). This is clearly absurd. This contradiction shows
that our assumption was wrong. Hence, we have proven our claim that there
exists some $j\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  $ satisfying \eqref{darij1.pf.t1.1}.]

Now, consider a $j\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  $ satisfying
\eqref{darij1.pf.t1.1}. (We have just proven that such a $j$ exists.) Then,
$\zeta^{j}$ is an $n$-th root of unity (since $\zeta$ is an $n$-th root of
unity) and thus lies on the unit circle. Moreover, \eqref{darij1.pf.t1.1}
shows that $\zeta^{j}$ is a complex number $z$ on the unit circle (actually,
an $n$-th root of unity) satisfying \eqref{darij1.eq.t1.eq}. Hence, such a $z$
exists. This proves Theorem 1. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

**Incomplete proof**

Assume first that both $A$ and $B$ are singular matrices. We have to prove that $\mathfrak R(f(z))\ge 0$ for some $z \in \partial D$ where $\partial D$ is the unit complex circle.

$f(z)$ is a complex polynomial whose integral on $\partial D$ vanishes. If $\mathfrak R(f(z))$ is always vanishing on $\partial D$, we’re done. If not it must take positive and negative values (if the integral of a non always vanishing continuous function is equal to zero, the function must take positive and negative values). Therefore we’re also done.

Now, removing our initial assumption, suppose for example that $\det B \neq 0$. We have to prove that
$$\mathfrak R(\det(C+zI)) \ge \det(C)+1$$ for some $z \in \partial D$ where $C =B^{-1}A$.

As $f(z) = \det(C+zI)=z^n +a_{n-1} z^{n-1} +\dots +a_1 z+\det(C),$ we’re left to prove that any real trigonometric polynomial 
$$\cos n\theta + a_{n-1} \cos (n-1)\theta + \dots a_1 \cos \theta -1$$

takes at least a non negative value for $\theta \in \mathbb R$.

**and here I don’t know how to follow on...**

Comment: As for your trigonometric polynomial: Sample it at the $n$ points $\theta = 2 \pi j / n$ for $j = 0,1,\ldots,n-1$. At least one of the values will be nonnegative, since the sum of all the $n$ values will be $0$. Of course, this is very much the same as my argument. However, you should also be careful about assuming $\det B \neq 0$; you cannot just say "by continuity" here, since your claim is existentially quantified over an infinite set (the unit circle). Of course, once you strengthen the claim by restricting $z$ to be an $n$-th root of unity, the argument will work.